# Context params ignored from web.xml by Myfaces with Quarkus

Tags: jsf, quarkus, myfaces

I'm working with quarkus and myfaces and I've stumbled into a few `ViewExpiredException`. Because my application heavily relies on `@Viewscoped` beans I wanted to check the number of `NUMBER_OF_VIEWS_IN_SESSION` and `NUMBER_OF_SEQUENTIAL_VIEWS_IN_SESSION` and it seems these `<context-param>` are ignored from the web.xml file.

I've made a minimal 'working' example here : https://github.com/Pilpin/mwe-quarkus-myfaces, it's an extremely simple app which just shows the values with the `#{initParam['x']}` el expression.

What I gather from this simple test is :

- `javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE` is ignored from web.xml but read from application.properties if present
- `org.apache.myfaces.USE_LAMBDA_METAFACTORY` and `org.apache.myfaces.EARLY_FLUSH_ENABLED` and some others are read from web.xml
- `org.apache.myfaces.NUMBER_OF_VIEWS_IN_SESSION` and `org.apache.myfaces.NUMBER_OF_SEQUENTIAL_VIEWS_IN_SESSION` are ignored but even more, the values obtained are not the default values from MyFaces (resp. 20 and 4, and I get 15 and 3, see https://myfaces.apache.org/#/core23next)

Would you have an idea of what is happening and how to fix it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i set some optimized params via the quarkus deployment here: https://github.com/apache/myfaces/blob/2.3-next/extensions/quarkus/deployment/src/main/java/org/apache/myfaces/core/extensions/quarkus/deployment/MyFacesProcessor.java#L327

please create a issue, so we can check why web.xml doesnt overwrite it. in worst case we have to remove this optimization.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so that's why the MyFaces default values are ignored as well. I would have created an issue on MyFaces' jira but [account creations are disabled](https://infra.apache.org/jira-guidelines.html) could you create the issue instead ? Or could you or someone you know create an account for me ?

Comment: I created issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MYFACES-4509

Comment: Do you know if there's an roadmap for the 2.3-next-M8 release ?