# What is the roadmap for MyFaces 2.3-next-M8

Tags: jsf, quarkus, myfaces

I'm currently developing a jsf app on quarkus using myfaces (2.3-next-M7) but due to a bug that [I raised here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74560196/context-params-ignored-from-web-xml-by-myfaces-with-quarkus) I can't use it in production and I am eagerly waiting for version 2.3-next-M8, would someone know when it is supposed to be released ?
I haven't found any information on [myfaces' site](https://myfaces.apache.org) or [myfaces' issue tracker](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MYFACES-4539?jql=project%20%3D%20MYFACES%20AND%20fixVersion%20%3D%202.3-next-M8)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: there is no roadmap per se but you can ask for a release on the mailing list